# Unable to install ansible-awx Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ansible-awx

I am trying to install AWX on Ubuntu 18.04 and i am getting the Error.

I have checked out the latest version of awx from github and tried running the install using

ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml -vvvv

```
TASK [local_docker : Start the containers] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /temp/awx/installer/roles/local_docker/tasks/compose.yml:25
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/docker/docker_service.py
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: sateesh
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~sateesh && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/sateesh/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555964996.64-166348838404173 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1555964996.64-166348838404173="` echo /home/sateesh/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555964996.64-166348838404173 `" ) && sleep 0'
<localhost> PUT /home/sateesh/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-18120SkKEmm/tmpaVUC61 TO /home/sateesh/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555964996.64-166348838404173/docker_service.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/sateesh/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555964996.64-166348838404173/ /home/sateesh/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555964996.64-166348838404173/docker_service.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/env python /home/sateesh/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555964996.64-166348838404173/docker_service.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/sateesh/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1555964996.64-166348838404173/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
The full traceback is:
  File "/tmp/ansible_oWaqla/ansible_module_docker_service.py", line 745, in cmd_up
    timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 559, in up
    'Encountered errors while bringing up the project.'

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "errors": [], 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_version": null, 
            "build": false, 
            "cacert_path": null, 
            "cert_path": null, 
            "debug": false, 
            "definition": null, 
            "dependencies": true, 
            "docker_host": null, 
            "files": null, 
            "filter_logger": false, 
            "hostname_check": false, 
            "key_path": null, 
            "nocache": false, 
            "project_name": null, 
            "project_src": "/tmp/awxcompose", 
            "pull": false, 
            "recreate": "smart", 
            "remove_images": null, 
            "remove_orphans": false, 
            "remove_volumes": false, 
            "restarted": false, 
            "scale": null, 
            "services": null, 
            "ssl_version": null, 
            "state": "present", 
            "stopped": false, 
            "timeout": 10, 
            "tls": null, 
            "tls_hostname": null, 
            "tls_verify": null
        }
    }, 
    "module_stderr": "Creating awx_web ... \r\n\r\u001b[1B", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "Error starting project unknown cause"
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/temp/awx/installer/install.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=8    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Not sure why it is failing.

I have the following versions of Ansible , pip & Docker

```
ansible 2.5.4
python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) [GCC 7.3.0]

Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
pip 19.0.3
```

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your solution and ran into the same issue.

My problem was that my host was running apache2, so the port 80 was already taken. After stopping and removing apache2, the build went through.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been following this question from the start as I did encounter the exact same message you did. I didn't have a possible solution to your question until now.

I just managed to install the latest version of AWX on my Ubuntu server running 18.04. What I've done to solve my issue (and I've tried this many times before) was:

1. Getting the latest AWX version from github
2. Edit the inventory file located in awx/installer keeping the path to postgres_data_dir the same as before
3. Use a command to kill all my running docker conatiners:

   ```
   docker container kill | docker container ls $(awk '{print $1}')
   ```

**Note!: I don't have any containers running except those used for AWX**

4. Removing all containers on my system:

   ```
   docker container rm <container>
   ```

**Note!: Again, I don't have any containers except those used for AWX**

*I've used the TAB key to let bash suggest the container names*

5. Used the ansible playbook for AWX:

   ```
   ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml
   ```

And thats it! This time I upgraded to the latest version of AWX. In my case, I wanted to update to the latest version. I don't know if you were updating or installing it "for the first time". But this is how I managed to do it, so maybe it works for you as well.

Good luck solving your issue if you haven't already.

P.S. Make sure project_src is not /tmp/awxcompose. This wil cause some issues I learned. It'll work, but if you reboot Ubuntu, AWX will run into a problem: [See this link](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/3705#issuecomment-484296440)